# Form wont work in ie

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have a form which works perfectly in chrome, but wont work at all in ie.

The code for the actual form is:

```
<div id="launch">
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" > 
        <input type="image" src="images/transparent.png" width="100" height="100" name="Launch" id="Launch" value="insertvaluehere" />
    </form> 
</div>
```

And i use this if statement to do code when the form is pressed:

```
if (($_POST['Launch']) && ($available1 == 0))
{
//Code for what is done.
}
```

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  Also you might want to get rid of those spaces between the attribute name and values and also wrap all your values in quotes...

Comment: Try setting a non-empty value for launch in the input, maybe IE isn't sending it because it thinks its empty (even though you have a space there).  What version of IE?

Comment: Okay ill try both thankyou, it is supposed to carry out a fair bit of code when the form is pressed and available is = 0

Comment: I edited your code, take a look at the few changes I made. You should probably place a value for the form as well.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong when you run the form in IE vs Chrome? Is it just flat out not showing up?

Comment: So what's happening?  You click and nothing happens?  Is the data getting submitted?  Can you tell if the PHP code is getting executed? Do you get a PHP error?

Comment: @jzacharia that didnt work either :S

Comment: @ernie i click and i dont think the php code within the if(($_POST['launch']) is being ran, there is nothing happening in IE but in chrome everything works perfectly

Comment: Working in IE now :) Thanks for all comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it to

```
<button type="submit" name="launch" id="Launch">Submit</button>
```

Then style it using

```
    #Launch{
        background-image:url(images/transparent.png); 
        width:100px; 
        height:100px; 
        dislay:block; 
        border:none; 
        color:transparent;
        background-color:none;
        cursor:pointer;
   }
```

Change:

```
if ($_POST)
{
    //execute
}
```

Comment: Could be an `<input type="submit" />`

Comment: Although this is a much better way to handle your styling, I don't know if this will solve browser compatibility issues.

Comment: Changing it to button stopped it working all together in chrome, doesn't seem to register the fact i submitted can you show me how you would use button with my code, not really used button normally stick to input

Comment: change it to <input type="submit" id="Launch" value="Launch" />

Comment: mine is image opps ill try it

Comment: hey thanks alot man :) changing type from image to submit worked perfect. gonna have an transparent input with an image under like the guy below said :)

Answer (score 0):

input types of image generally do not submit values, but instead submit the coordinates where the user clicked on the image (generally intended for use as an image map).

If you're committed to using an image for submit, you have a two main options:

1. Regular submit type `<input>` with a hidden field with the value you want (you could use CSS to style the submit into an image)
2. a `<button>`